# Why does $K/I \cong I \otimes K/R_K$ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field, and $R_K$ be its ring of integers.
Let $I$ be  fractional ideal of $R_K$.

Why does $K/I \cong I \otimes K/R_K$ hold as $R_K$ module?

My try; $0→R_K→K→K/R_K→0$ is exact
Tensoring $I$ and using first isomorphism theorem we get
$ I \otimes K/R_K$ is isom to $(I \otimes K)/(I \otimes R_K)$. But I cannot proceed from here, maybe I should choice another way to prove the statement.

Comment: What do you mean by **its** fractional ideal?

Comment: I modified a lot of typos, thank you for your help.